# how to generate a new app signing key and add to existing keystore in android

Tags: android, apk, keytool

I have started to work on a setup where there are around 10 different apps. The signing keys of all the apps are kept in a single keystore and differentiated from each other by alias name while signing the app manually using apksigner/jarsigner.

Now for one new app, I have a add new key for it to this keystore. I tried to find a way to generate a new key and store it in this keystore but could not succeed.

I know how to create a new keystore using keytool but this is not what I need.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: you can try using external applications like keystore explorer to manage your keys.  http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html . its UI is quite intuitive (no need to run keytool on the console).  you can add/remove/change your keys in a keystore file.

Answer (score 0):

Can this [java crypto library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) helps?

I used this for keystore read and write in android, key generation is also available.